# Log4j2 - Unsupported Parameters

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am trying following very simple configuration of log4j to try and understand the library. I have put the file in a sub package of my main package

```
Main Package
  |
  |__Logging Package <-  XML file is here
```

log4j xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
          value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I am getting the desired log when I execute my program from with in the IntelliJ but if I create a jar file and execute it I start getting following log4j2 initialization error.

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16
 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at positi
on 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at positio
n 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at positi
on 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position
54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56
 in conversion pattern.
```

and then for every log in my application, log4j spits the pattern I have specified in the configuration as is on the screen without any other information.

I am using following log4j dependency on a Windows 7 desktop.

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
```

I have following configured for Java version in my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is for Log4j 1.x, not 2.x.

Comment: Thank you. I find it really strange that there were no complaints when I was running from within the IDE.

Comment: I have the same error, what should be changed please ?

Comment: I am also looking for the solution. What is the change needed in the pom file ?